# Loop through output of command searching for number over 50

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through the output of a command, for example

```
John 45
Ted 35
Eric 65
Bob 25
Jeff 50
```

It will loop through one line at a time, it will print a message for any line over 60, so Eric will would be printed out

```
/dev/mapper/vg_bob-lv_root 31
/dev/sda1 12
/dev/sdb1 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No looping needed as `awk` is much simpler for this:

```
awk '$2>60{print $1}' file
Eric
```

Comment: What if the command has multiple pipes? Its not pulling from a file

Comment: df -hP | awk {'print$1" "$5'} | grep '/dev' | sed "s/%$//"

Comment: You can use: `df -hP | awk {'print$1" "$5'} | sed "s/%$//" | awk '/\/dev/ && $2>60{print $1}'`

Comment: Can you paste output of `df -hP | awk {'print$1" "$5'} | sed "s/%$//"` in your question (not in comments)

Comment: OK but in your output there is no record `> 60` so obviously awk won't print anything. Lower 60 to 30 and you will see `/dev/mapper/vg_bob-lv_root` in output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure shell solution which reads from a file:

```
$ while read name age ; do [ "$age" -gt 60 ] && echo $name ; done<file
Eric
```

If the data is coming from a command, then use this form:

```
$ command | while read name age ; do [ "$age" -gt 60 ] && echo $name ; done
```